# Formula for finding income needed?

Tags: income, expenses

If I have X dollars in committed money each year (expenses, savings, investments, etc.), and I need to pay 30% income tax (simplifying), what is the formula for figuring what my income should be to cover my the costs?

I tried "income = expenses * 1.3", but that doesn't seem right to me because the 30% is on the lower expenses amount not on the total.

Comment: 30% might be a _marginal_ tax rate for some people, but (in the US, at least),  I doubt that the _net_ tax rate (total tax paid divided by gross income) is 30% for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take home X with taxes of 30%, the remaining 70% of your income must equal or exceed X.

Income * 0.7 >= X

Income >= X / 0.7

More generally, that's income of needs/(100%-tax) or more. Basic algebra.

Note: This assumes you have calculated needs correctly (remember that costs differ in different places) and that you have included all taxes (in the US there are federal income taxes plus some mix of state and local income taxes.)